# Set Recat LInk to Button when button click call the function & after Navigite to Another Component

Tags: reactjs, button

I need to set Link to navigate another component & also I want to call function when same button clicked.

```
addValue(evt)
    {
      evt.preventDefault();
      if(this.state.value !=undefined)
      {
        alert('Your input value is: ' + this.state.value)
        localStorage.setItem('reg_no',this.state.value);
        alert(localStorage.getItem('reg_no'));

      }

    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.addValue}>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput} placeholder="Enter Hospital Registration Number"/><br/><br/>
            <Button type="submit" value="Enter" onClick={()=>this.addValue}> Enter</Button>


            </form>
          );
    }
```

This is my react code. I want to set Link to Enter button. How I do it?
(suppose i want to load 'Home' component by url '/homeurl'

Answer (score 1):

try to use React-router redirect method

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

then use a state prop to identify that you click operation has been finished like this

```
state = {
    open:false;
    }
addValue(evt)
{
  evt.preventDefault();
  if(this.state.value !=undefined)
  {
    alert('Your input value is: ' + this.state.value)
    localStorage.setItem('reg_no',this.state.value);
    alert(localStorage.getItem('reg_no'));
this.setState({open:true});
  }

}

render() { 
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.addValue}>
    {this.state.open? (
    <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/home"
          }}
    ):null}
        <input type="text" onChange={this.updateInput} placeholder="Enter Hospital Registration Number"/><br/><br/>
        <Button type="submit" value="Enter" onClick={()=>this.addValue}> Enter</Button>


        </form>
      );
}
```

Comment: actually i want to load another component (like as another page). not a redirect